# Como Insertar un id que se genero de una consulta a otra tabla PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el código que me manda el id, código donde muestro alumno y selecciono uno para agregar un pago.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="add_pago.php?id=<?php echo (int)$alumno['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  title="Agregar Pago" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Y otros fragmentos de código donde muestro al usuario pero no me agrega el el dato del ID del alumno en la otra tabla.

El Id del alumno lo quiero insertar en otra tabla. Por mas que he realizado pruebas y pruebas no logro hacerlo
No logra insertar el ID del alumno en la otra tabla.

Solo inserta los datos nuevos.

```php
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_pago'])){
   $req_fields = array( 'mes_pagado', 'monto');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $mensualidad  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['mensualidad']));
     $id_alumno   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['id']));
     $horario_clase  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['horario_clase']));
     $mes_pagado   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['mes_pagado']));
     $monto   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['monto']));

$date    = make_date();
$query  = "INSERT INTO mesualidades (";
$query .=" mensualidad, fecha_pago, id_alumno, mes_pagado, monto";
$query .=") VALUES (";
$query .=" '{$mensualidad}', '{$date}', '{$id_alumno}', '{$mes_pagado}', '{$monto}'";
$query .=")";

<label for="monto" class="control-label">MONTO</label>
  <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="monto" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="mensualidad" class="control-label">MENSUALIDAD</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mensualidad" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($alumno['mensualidad'])); ?>" disabled>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="id" class="control-label">ID ALUMNO</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($alumno['id'])); ?>" disabled>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"> 

</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <button type="submit" name="add_pago" class="btn btn-danger">AGREGAR PAGO</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="pagos.php"><input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-info"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido. Por favor, muestra el código de las 2 tablas que mencionas en tu publicacion. Selecciona Editar para añadir la informacion

Comment: Hola alexander, el codigo esta muy mal escrito o esta expresado de una forma diferente a lo convencional, para preguntar aqui se necesita un conocimiento minimo y mostrando un codigo claro de lo que se esta tratando de resolver. Si pudieras compartir mas informacion de lo que estas tratando de resolver de una manera clara te pudieramos ayudar mas.

Comment: Lo que no logro agregar a la tabla esta ahí. Es el value mensualidad y value id de usuario.  Estos los mando traer de otra consulta. Tal vez no se como expresar al ser nuevo en desarrollo